# Creating checksum/reversable hash for transaction-id

Tags: php

I am writing a small piece of software.

Let's assume the following case: A person wants to make a payment to a bank account, and needs to put in a reference number. The recipient asked to put the number "2345" as a payment reference, so that he can identify the payment and trace the reference number / payment back to the person.

The problem: Sometimes users type the wrong reference number. For example: "2345" is typed as "234" or "23455", which causes confusion.

A possible solution: Generate a reference number like this: ??????????2345 where ? is a numeric character. So, if we can generate a checksum or hash (????????????), that can be then decoded to the number and then traced back to 2345. A simple example: (2345*5) (2345) = "11725 2345". If the first part of the reference number divided by 5 is equal to the second part, it's a valid reference number.

The "checksum/hash" must be 20 numeric characters or less, so we can then append a 6-character reference number (reference-number must be less than 26 characters).

Ideally, it would be fixed-length (20 characters for example) and easily be decoded via a php function.

I tried using crc32, but to my knowledge it's not reversible.

Hope someone can give me a direction so I can dig deeper into this. As always, many thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want to add redundancy to the data so in case the data is "damaged", it can be restored from the included redundancy? Then I'd probably simply have the customer repeat the number: `45/2345/23` - can be reconstructed if either end is cut off. But what if the customer writes the redundancy incorrectly? Have redundancy for the redundancy? Thereby making the number longer and longer, increasing the likelihood of a typo? As long as humans are involved, I'm not sure there's an adequate solution really...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right about humans being a very unreliable factor in our equation :)